# Responsive design issue in small screens - Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having cards which show horizontally. Please see the image to get an idea. When I have a big header, in `sm` screens the cards inside the columns wrap unevenly.

```
<div class="col-sm-4" data-ng-repeat="card in cards">
     <div class="card">
       <div class="cardHeader">Big Header issue</div>
        .....
     </div>
</div>
```

[image]

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Use something like http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Good nice e.g. But unfortunately i cannot use Jquery.

Comment: @Anup Am I right in thinking that currently, it's one card-to-one-column? Need to see the rest of the HTML! =)

Comment: Yes...It is 1 card to 1 `col-sm-4` column.

Comment: Then it's not going to adapt to different sizes of cards, thus it's currently collapsing correctly depending on the above column height. I'll post an answer html that should fix it

Comment: You don't have to use it with jQuery. You can use it in a normal OOP way (e.g. `new Masonry(document.getElementById("myGridHolder"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

You could use CSS ellipsis like this to append '..' to the heading when it's too long:

```
.cardHeader {
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/115420 (uses `panel-heading` instead)

**Option 2**

Another option is to use a `clearfix` div after every 3 'col-sm-4' div..

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/115421

---

**Related**
[Bootstrap row with columns of different height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310912/bootstrap-row-with-columns-of-different-height/22311212#22311212)

Comment: Option 2 won't be possible for me...as i am looping through Data.

Comment: Then use CSS! something like this: `.col-sm-4:nth-child(3n+3):after {/*insert clearfix here*/}`

Answer (score 0):

do you use the row class? something like this:

```
<div class ='row'>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="card">
       <div class="cardHeader">Big Header issue</div>
        .....
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="card">
       <div class="cardHeader">Big Header issue</div>
        .....
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="card">
       <div class="cardHeader">Big Header issue</div>
        .....
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, which is slightly more HTML heavy but keeps the boxes/cards responsive:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card biggercard">
                       <div class="cardHeader">Biggest Header</div>
                        1
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card">
                       <div class="cardHeader">Second Header</div>
                        2
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card">
                       <div class="cardHeader">Third</div>
                        3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card">
                       <div class="cardHeader">Fourth</div>
                        4
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card">
                       <div class="cardHeader">5th</div>
                        5
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card">
                       <div class="cardHeader">6th</div>
                         6
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### **Demo FIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/La3H2/**

Comment: I forgotten to tell in my question that data is looping from an object.

Comment: Is it AngularJS you're using? I'd be surprised if it hasn't got MOD for breaking into a new row or etc =) nevermind!