# Bootstrap row with columns of different height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I currently have something like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">Content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Content</div>
</div>
```

Now assuming that, `content` was boxes of different height, with all the same width - how could I keep the same "grid based layout" and yet have all the boxes line up under each other, instead of in perfect lines.

Currently TWBS will place the next line of `col-md-4` under the longest element in the previous third row., thus each row of items is perfectly aligned an clean - while this is awesome I want each item to fall directly under the last element ("Masonry" layout)

Answer (score 201, accepted):

This is a popular Bootstrap question, so I've **updated** and expanded the answer for Bootstrap 3, Bootstrap 4 and Bootstrap 5...

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2021)**

Bootstrap columns still use flexbox, but the card-columns previously used to create a Masonry like layout [have been removed](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/card/#masonry). For Bootstrap 5 the recommended method is to use the Masonry JS plugin:
[Bootstrap 5 Masonry Example](https://codeply.com/p/yrjCBwUeKR)

**Bootstrap 4 (update 2018)**

All columns are equal height in **Bootstrap 4** because it uses flexbox by default, so the "height issue" is not a problem. Additionally, Bootstrap 4 includes this type of multi-columns solution:
[Bootstrap 4 Masonry cards Demo](http://codeply.com/go/q03ZHDeSGN).

**Bootstrap 3 (original answer -- pre flexbox)**

The **Bootstrap 3** "[height problem](https://medium.com/wdstack/varying-column-heights-in-bootstrap-4e8dd5338643)" occurs because the columns use `float:left`. When a column is “floated” it’s taken out of the normal flow of the document. It is shifted to the left or right until it touches the edge of its containing box. So, when you have **uneven column heights**, the correct behavior is to stack them to the closest side.

[image: Bootstrap uneven wrapping columns]

**Note**: The options below are applicable for [**column wrapping** scenarios](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-example-wrapping) where there are **more than 12 col units in a single `.row`**. For readers that don't understand why there would ever be **more than 12 cols in a row**, or think the solution is to "use separate rows" [should read this first](https://medium.com/wdstack/bootstrap-exceed-12-columns-in-a-row-b551eeddf62b)

---

**There are a few ways to fix this..** (updated for 2018)

**1 - The 'clearfix' approach** ([recommended by Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets)) like this (requires iteration every *X* columns). This will force a wrap every *X* number of columns...

[image]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">Content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Content</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Content</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Content</div>
</div>
```

[Clearfix Demo (single tier)](http://www.bootply.com/fJ0JOF7yuo)

[Clearfix Demo (responsive tiers)](http://bootply.com/89910) - eg. `col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3`

There is also a [CSS-only variation](http://www.codeply.com/go/lUbs1JgXUd) of the 'clearfix'
[CSS-only clearfix with tables](http://www.codeply.com/go/6YTTnADEHq)

---

**2 - Make the columns the same height (using flexbox):**

Since the issue is caused by the *difference* in height, you can make columns *equal* height across each row. Flexbox is the best way to do this, and is **natively supported in Bootstrap 4**...

[image]

```
.row.display-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row.display-flex > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

[Flexbox equal height Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/KppyJTTbwM)

---

**3 - Un-float the columns an use inline-block instead..**

Again, the height problem only occurs because the columns are floated. Another option is to set the columns to `display:inline-block` and `float:none`. This also provides more flexibility for vertical-alignment. However, with this solution there must be **no HTML whitespace between columns**, otherwise the [inline-block elements have additional space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5078297/171456) and will wrap prematurely.

[Demo of inline block fix](http://www.codeply.com/go/xiwLUjPz9T/bootstrap-cols-inline-block)

---

**4 - CSS3 columns approach (Masonry/Pinterest like solution)..**

This is not native to Bootstrap 3, but another approach using [CSS multi-columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts). One downside to this approach is the column order is top-to-bottom instead of left-to-right. **Bootstrap 4 includes this type of
solution**:
[**Bootstrap 4 Masonry** cards Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/q03ZHDeSGN).

[Bootstrap 3 multi-columns Demo](http://www.bootply.com/120682)

**5 - Masonry JavaScript/jQuery approach**

Finally, you may want to use a plugin such as Isotope/Masonry:
[image]

[Bootstrap Masonry Demo](http://www.bootply.com/108697)
[Masonry Demo 2](http://www.codeply.com/go/UYk8DzIDv6)

---

[More on Bootstrap Variable Height Columns](https://medium.com/wdstack/varying-column-heights-in-bootstrap-4e8dd5338643)

---

Comment: Here is a good guideline on vertical alignment in bootstrap https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/. Particularly vertical alignment and class "row align-items-start"

Comment: WooW! you earn my up vote for this https://www.bootply.com/120682. With Masonry plugin, it looks good on page load not good when you drag to adjust the screen width

Answer (score 14):

For some reason this worked for me without the .display-flex class

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row > [class*='col-'] {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: This did work for me. Only i put second css to .col property

Answer (score -1):

I created another extension (which also is reactive) to the bootstrap row. You can try something like this:

`.row.flexRow   { display: flex;  flex-wrap: wrap;}`