# Twitter Bootstrap - Style more than 12 columns in a row?

Tags: css, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code which might or might not give more than 12 columns in a row.
How can I make it look nice if there is more than 12 columns?

```
<div collapse="gpCollapse">
  <div ng-repeat="item in revealedCtrl.greatPersons" class="thumbnail col-md-3">
    <img ng-src="/images/useritems/{{item.greatperson.image}}" tooltip="{{item.greatperson.name}}"/>

    <div class="caption">
      <h3 class="text-center">{{item.greatperson.name}}</h3>

      <p class="text-justify">
        {{item.greatperson.description}}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: 'look nice' is rather a general term. Can you be more specific?

Comment: My apologies, I thought it was self explanatory. I would like the images to be displayed floating left. In the image above you see two images floating right, then finally last one alone in a row. To me it looks like it should be room to have 2 rows. One with 4 items, the other with 3

Comment: This looks like a place that flexbox would come in handy. Bootstrap grid functionality is pretty limited.

Comment: That's because the columns are of varied heights. None of your floats are cleared so it appears like that.

Comment: @George Sorry, I am very bad at CSS. I also figured it was something like that. How can I fix it? Give it a fixed height?

Comment: @J4G: I will not change to another framework. I will have to fix it with what is available in the twitter bootstrap universe

Comment: Giving the columns a fixed height (perhaps a `min-height`) would certainly solve this problem. But you may only want the minimum heights to be applied when the columns are not stacked up (non-mobile devices)

Comment: [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) isn't another framework, it's a new CSS feature

Comment: @J4G A CSS feature that bootstrap is in fact taking advantage of in [version 4](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2015/08/19/bootstrap-4-alpha/) :)

Comment: Ditch Bootstrap's grid in favor of Flexbox ;)

Comment: There are multiple ways to fix this issue explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310912/bootstrap-row-with-columns-of-different-height/22311212#22311212

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a constant height to "thumbnail" class.

Comment: What should this height be?

Comment: Thanks. This was the easiest. I set it to 320px.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your layout does not end up looking nice is the variable height of the column content, specifically in

```
<div class="caption">
```

use css to give the column divs (.thumbnail)

```
position: relative;
// to make space for absolutely positioned caption
padding-bottom: 40px;
```

and .caption

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
```

Comment: This almost worked. However, the text suddenly is inside the image. Look at the following: http://bildr.no/view/R2g1YzNq

Comment: play with the the amount of pixels padding-bottom of .thumbnail use that same amount of pixels for .caption height. This can lead to text overflowing the container, but you can make that look better using overflow:hidden or text-overflow: ellipsis, etc.