# Bootstrap thumbnails position

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap thumbnail class to display a list of players as shown in photo below. The problem some player names exceed a single line and go for a second line which do not make the same dimension for thumbnails. And the real problem I faced is the wrong positioning of the thumbnails as seen in the second row in the photo. How can I fix it? Here is the code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div ng-repeat="player in $ctrl.players">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img ng-src="{{player.imgpath}}" height="100" width="121" alt="" style="border-radius: 100%"/>
      <div class="caption">
        <h4><span class="badge">{{player.jersey}}</span> {{player.name}}</h4>
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <td><b>Position</b></td>
            <td>{{player.position}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: For the names, you can give a specific height for the thumbnails. Using `white-space: nowrap` might make the names go out of the thumbnails' borders as it prevents line breaks. But for the wrong positioning, it might be a problem with your script.

Comment: This is the classic Bootstrap [height problem](https://medium.com/wdstack/varying-column-heights-in-bootstrap-4e8dd5338643). Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310912/bootstrap-rows-with-columns-of-different-height and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38730889/bootstrap-grid-system-new-line-does-not-look-nice/38745719

Answer (score 0):

You can use nowrap on the names. That way they will only be one line
`.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap ;
}`

Otherwise i'd recommend using flexbox, not tables to display the team members. It's responsive and you won't have issues like the one on your second row.

Comment: nowrap is not good when I have long names like Bastian SCHWEINSTEIGER, it goes outside the border. Also, I can't use flex box since I'm using bootstrap 3.x

Answer (score 0):

You can use display:inline-block and float:none;

```
.col-md-*,.col-sm-*,.col-xs-*{
 float:none;
 display: inline-block;
margin-left: -4px;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Your solution displays 1 thumbnail per row. I don't want this. Also when changing the size of the page the player name for long one like SCHWEINSTEIGER goes much outside the border.

Answer (score 0):

```
.caption h4{
   display: table;
 }

.caption h4 .badge{
display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: The solution truncates the name of long player names. I don't want this. I don't mind if the content goes for a second line and thought give a larger size for the thumbnail. I just don't want the wrong display that appeared in the first photo I displayed in the main question.

Comment: Again no. Same and even worse. I attached the display output