# CSS layout with difference on mobile vs desktop

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

**Using CSS, how can I achieve the following layout?**

Notice that the *order* of the elements is different on mobile vs desktop!

[image]

Currently, I am using *bootstrap 4*. The following code "works" for the desktop version, however, does not work for the mobile version.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">    
            <div class="a">
                A
            </div>
            <div class="d">
                D
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="b">
                B
            </div>
            <div class="c">
                C
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**How can I achieve the desired layout? I am considering solutions using:**

- Bootstrap 4
- Flexbox
- CSS Grid

Answer (score 2):

The Bootstrap 4 way to get the order you want, and make columns "fit" together is to disable flexbox and use floats for the desktop layout...

**"Fit" masonry layout with floats and reordering**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters d-block">
        <div class="col-md-4 float-left">    
            <div class="a">
                A
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 float-left">
            <div class="b">
                B
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 float-right">
            <div class="c">
                C
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 float-left">    
            <div class="d">
                D
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo https://www.codeply.com/go/U4zuuyfHQV

**Same heights layout with flexbox and reordering**

```
   <div class="row text-white no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="a">
                A
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="b">
                B
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 order-last order-md-0">
            <div class="d">
                D
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="c">
                C
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Demo https://www.codeply.com/go/U4zuuyfHQV (option 2)

---

Related: [Bootstrap row with columns of different height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310912/bootstrap-row-with-columns-of-different-height/22311212#22311212)

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for a flexbox version now. There was one a few minutes ago, but it was deleted.

Comment: Flexbox won't work for this because you can't re-order child divs in different parents. That's why you need to use floats in this specific case.

Comment: They do not have to be in different parent divs. They can all be in the same parent div if necessary.

Comment: Exactly, but then they won't "fit" together like the "masonry" pattern shown in the desktop image because flexbox makes columns the same height.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying. But it just so happens that in this particular case, I don't need A and B to be of different heights on desktop. They can be the same height on desktop. As long as the order is correct, I am happy. At least for now.

Comment: I answered the original question "bootstrap 4/flexbox", and then it was edited which changed the scope of the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you're already using Bootstrap, you can use pushes and pulls to achieve this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="a col-md-4">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="b col-md-8">
      B
    </div>
    <div class="c col-md-8 col-md-push-4">
      C
    </div>
    <div class="d col-md-4 col-md-pull-8">
      D
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See this example: https://codepen.io/bretteast/pen/VxKyLX

And these docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-column-ordering