# Different height columns inline using Masonry jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry

I have multiple divs creating a grid pattern on my page. The width of each div is set with bootstrap to all equally be the same in this case the class 'col-md-3' is added to make each 25% of the width of the page. Each div is either 400px or 800px in height. This is where I am having a problem.

According to this question sollution 5 is what I need to do to achieve the required effect: [Bootstrap row with columns of different height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310912/bootstrap-row-with-columns-of-different-height)

I have followed the second demo however, I have no errors and I still have an offset in my Grid pattern, can someone please advise?

I have noticed that position absolute has been added to each div, his is making them layer on top of each other instead of being in the grid?

```
<div class="blockOut row">
    <div class="col-md-3 blocks short">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 blocks short">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 blocks tall">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 blocks short">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 blocks short">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 blocks tall">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 blocks short">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 blocks short">
    </div>
</div>

.blockOut {
    margin-top: 7.5vh;
}

.blocks {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.row').masonry({
      itemSelector : '.col-md-3'
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `display:none;` will make everything with the `.blocks` class invisible. If you are working in-line with another group of blocks, it's possible you're looking at the wrong group. Some of the other CSS attributes for your `.blocks` class are not doing anything useful, unless this is an excerpt from a larger project.

I also see some custom CSS for the `.row` class in the demo which you have not included here, although you are using the class in your template. The `background-clip: content-box;` attribute prevents the blocks from overlapping.

```
.row [class*='col-'] {
  background-color: #cceeee;
  background-clip: content-box;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
```

Otherwise, the code you provided renders properly for me.

Comment: Hey Ben, yea sorry the display:none is changed by javascript as an animation on load. There is also a background image which is dynamically loaded using javascript which makes more sense with regards to some other attributes.. so theoretically this should work.. however it doesn't I will look further into this and upload the answer when I fix it. Thank you.

Comment: I see. In that case I think the problem is in part of the code you did not provide. If you update the question with all the relevant code I'd be happy to take another look.