# Bootstrap: How to force a list of div elements to stay two per line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a grid of Client Cards that change sizes depending on the width of the window(1 per row/2 per row/3 per row...). Theses Card's height expand using Bootstrap when you reduce the size of the window.

The problem is when the first card (or second when 3 per row) grow in height there's not enough space for another card under it so the rightmost cards pile up.

**Here's a example of the problem.**
[image: Example]

I've tried `display: inline;` and its different values on the div but can't get the needed result.

Code of every div:

```
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="widget widget-client">
        <div class="client-profile">...Profile Picture...</div>
        <div>...Infos....</div>
        <div class="widget-actions clearfix">...Bottom actions...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My goal is to always have 2 (or 3, depending on the screen size) cards per row.**

How can I achieve that result?

Comment: Since Bootstrap 3 was pre-flexbox, this is going to be a problem. Are you able use a set height for your widget div?

Comment: it uses min-heigth: 180px; but I want it to increase if the content cannot fit.

Comment: This is a common problem and has been answered before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310912/bootstrap-row-with-columns-of-different-height . In my opinion though the layout will look awful if your widgets have varying height.

Comment: also there is no col-xl-* class in Bootstrap 3 :)

Comment: @slynagh Its a custom class made by us, its there for dem 4k sreens that most users dont have (only devs really have 4k).
Thanks for the link btw the clearfix solution worked