# Bootstrap 5: align the cards vertically close to another card

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I've been building the responsive card collection with Bootstrap 5 and vue 3. With the `container` and the `row` classes, I can make the cards align to each at the same level. However, to make the timestamp (`card-footer`) attached to the bottom, I also use `h-100` within the card classes. The timestamp is rendered as expected, but there's a gap between each row if the content changes, illustrated below.

[image]

I want to make the card align vertically close to have the same gap between the cards.

[image]

Is there any way for doing vertical alignment with Bootstrap?

Here is part of the code for now (with vue3):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="card h-100 shadow-sm mt-3 mx-1" v-for="(newsPiece, index) in newsCollection" :key="index">
        <!-- image can toggle description -->
        <img :src="newsPiece.urlToImage" alt="image link lost" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          :data-bs-target="'#collapseImage'+index">
        <!-- title -->
        <h5><a :href="newsPiece.url" target="_blank">{{ newsPiece.title }}</a></h5>
        <!-- toggle content from image -->
        <div class="collapse" :id="'collapseImage'+index">
          <div class="card-body-noborder">
            <!-- {{ newsPiece.description }} -->
            <span v-html="newsPiece.description"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          {{ newsPiece.publishedAt.replace('T',' ').replace('Z','') }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It is called _mansonry grid_ and it is usually done with JavaScript.

Comment: Only `col-*` should be the children of the `row`, and then `card h-100` would go inside the `col-*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310912/bootstrap-row-with-columns-of-different-height/22311212#22311212), you're looking for a "Masonry" layout. The [recommended method for Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/card/#masonry) is to use the Masonry JS plugin.