# Boostrap - Make column fill leftover space of previous row column above

Tags: html

I want to push a bootstrap column up in order to fill the leftover space of the last column in the previous row like this:

[image: This is what happens]

[image: This is what I want]

Is it possible?

Comment: I recommend you to check this title->> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310912/bootstrap-row-with-columns-of-different-height

Comment: I know this solution but if I increase the height of the column above, then I get a lot of blank space. I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Also interested in a solution...